# can't run flutter app : Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

Tags: android, flutter

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\WINDOWS.android\debug.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)